# How to add custom CSS class to leaflet tilelayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, css

I am working with mapbox.js and leaflet to create a map with a number of overlapping tilelayers. I want to apply some custom CSS to only selected tilelayers, and thus assign these layers to an additional custom CSS class like this:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer(layername).addTo(map);
layer.getContainer().className += ' custom';
```

Unfortunately, the above did not do the trick, though. Any hints on how to assign a custom CSS class to a given tilelayer in leaflet/mapbox would be very welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added as a new feature in Leaflet [just a few days ago](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4553). That feature will be part of the v1.0.0-rc2 release.

Also, your method works well, as [demonstrated here](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/rel/edit?html,output).

Comment: Indeed it works - I had it in the wrong place in my JS file. Sorry for that.

Comment: ?? where the code? please copy/paste here