# How do I add custom CSS class to an image overlayer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have been using Leaflet's imageOverlay quite frequently to overlay images in a Leaflet map pane.  Now I would like to apply a custom CSS to the overlaid image dynamically.  I came across Raphael's post on [How to add custom CSS class to leaflet tilelayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195271/how-to-add-custom-css-class-to-leaflet-tilelayer).  How do I extend this method to an image layer?  I tried the following using IvanSanchez example but could not get it to work. I was trying to apply CSS filter: grayscale(100%) to both the under-laid tiles and the overlaid image (a pineapple).  The tiles and grid lines became gray scale but not the overlaid pineapple image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Leaflet JS Bin</title>
<style>
#map {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
}

.leaflet-layer.foobar img {
  border: 5px solid red;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
var myCenter = new L.LatLng(50.5, 30.51);
var map = new L.Map('map', {center: myCenter, zoom: 1});

var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
}).addTo(map);

positron.getContainer().className += ' foobar';

url="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg";
pic=L.imageOverlay(url,[[0, -90], [90, 100]]);
map.addLayer(pic);
pic.getContainer().className += ' foobar';

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have something like

```
var pic = L.imageOverlay(url,[[0, -90], [90, 100]]);
```

Then running [`getElement()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#imageoverlay-getelement) on your instance of `L.ImageOverlay` like:

```
var imgElement = pic.getElement();
```

Will get you an [instance of `HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). You can then access its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property, which exposes an `add()` method. e.g.:

```
pic.getElement().classList.add('myCustomCSSClass');
```

Comment: So, using the CSS definition in this example, should the last statement be pic.getElement().classList.add('foobar') or pic.getElement().classList.add('.leaflet-layer.foobar')?  I tried both but they did not change the pineapple to gray scale.

Comment: Please refer to the method reference and examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: In your case, the problem in in the CSS selector in your CSS style declaration. `.foobar img` would apply to an `<img>` element _inside_ a `<whatever class='foobar'>` container.

Comment: I have found out that this is the required CSS style declaration:
.leaflet-image-layer.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

Comment: The javascript implementation is pic.getElement().classList.add('gray')